# Styling facebook share post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I inherited a new client along with her code, who maintains a blog.  Currently when she goes to share on facebook it only pulls in her `blog.picture`, `blog.title`, and `blog.title` again.  I have been trying to figure out how to add in the `blog.body` but cannot seem to figure out how this is done, or the best way to do it.

This is the facebook share post code

    `<%= link_to "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + root_url + "solblog?blog_id=" + @selected_blog.id.to_s + "&t=" + @selected_blog.body, class: "share_icon", title: "Share on Facebook", target: "_blank" do %> <%= image_tag "share_facebook.jpg" %>
    <% end %>`

Is this what is controlling what is shared?  If it is, why will it not pull in the body?  If it is not, how do I control what shows up when the blog is being shared?

Answer (score 0):

The `sharer.php` only takes the URL as parameter, all other data will get read from the Open Graph tags of that URL: http://ogp.me/

Your code is very old and deprecated for some years already.